# (434) WSA E TimedOut: Lost socket connection to the Teradata server in R

Tags: r, odbc, teradata

I am trying to connect to Teradata in R using an ODBC connection. I use the same configuration on my local machine and it works. However, when I connect through a server it throws the below error.
I have set up an ODBC DSA connection using the teradata driver with all the connection credentials.
How do I fix this?

```
    >   con <- odbcConnect("Terr_Con")
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=Terr_Con") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 434, message [Teradata][socket error] (434) WSA E TimedOut: Lost socket connection to the Teradata server
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=Terr_Con") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Comment: Seems to indicate a network-related problem (firewall rule, routing issue, etc.) or perhaps an issue with DNS resolution from the server.

Comment: See if you can telnet to the target on port 1025 (assuming it's using the default port).